# Pytest: parametrizing tests that require a slow initialization

Tags: python, pytest

I want to do tests with randomized parameters of a class with a very slow **init** method. The tests themself are very quick, but require a time consuming initialization step.
Of course. I do something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("params", LIST_OF_RANDOMIZED_PARAMS)
def test_one(params):
    state = very_slow_initialization(params)
    assert state.fast_test()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("params", LIST_OF_RANDOMIZED_PARAMS)
def test_two(params):
    state = very_slow_initialization(params)
    assert state.another_fast_test()
```

From my unsuccessful tries so far I've learnt:

1. initializing a Testclass with a parametrized set_class(params) method is not supported
2. Using a fixture that initialized the class still calls the slow initialization every time
3. I could create a list with all initialized states in advance, however they demand a lot of memory. Furthermore sometimes I like to rune a lot of randomized tests overnight and just stop them the next morning. This this I would need to know precisely how many tests I should to so that all initializations are finished before that.
4. If possible I would prefer a solution that runs both tests for the first parameter, then runs both with the second parameter and so on.

There is probably a really simple solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html) is a solution for you. Lifetime of fixture might be a single test, class, module or whole test session.

> fixture management scales from simple unit to complex functional testing, allowing to parametrize fixtures and tests according to configuration and component options, or to re-use fixtures across function, class, module or whole test session scopes.

Per [Fixture availability paragraph](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-availability), you need to define feature in class, or on module level.

Consider using module-scoped ones (pay attention, that initialization launched only once):

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def heavy_context():
    # Use your LIST_OF_RANDOMIZED_PARAMS randomized parameters here
    # to initialize whatever you want.
    print("Slow fixture initialized")
    return ["I'm heavy"]


def test_1(heavy_context):
    print(f"\nUse of heavy context: {heavy_context[0]}")


def test_2(heavy_context):
    print(f"\nUse of heavy context: {heavy_context[0]}")
```

Tests output:

```
...
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_basic.py::test_1 Slow fixture initialized
PASSED                                             [ 50%]
Use of heavy context: I'm heavy

test_basic.py::test_2 PASSED                                             [100%]
Use of heavy context: I'm heavy
```

Now, if you need it to be assertion safe (release resources even when test fails), consider creating `heavy_context` in a context-manager manner (much more details here: [Fixture, Running multiple assert statements safely](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#running-multiple-assert-statements-safely)):

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def heavy_context():

    print("Slow context initialized")
    obj = ["I'm heavy"]

    # It is mandatory to put deinitialiation into "finally" scope
    # otherwise in case of exception it won't be executed
    try:
        yield obj[0]
    finally:
        print("Slow context released")


def test_1(heavy_context):
    # Pay attention, that in fact heavy_context now
    # is what we initialized as 'obj' in heavy_context
    # function.
    print(f"\nUse of heavy context: {heavy_context}")


def test_2(heavy_context):
    print(f"\nUse of heavy context: {heavy_context}")
```

Output:

```
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_basic.py::test_1 Slow context initialized
PASSED                                             [ 50%]
Use of heavy context: I'm heavy

test_basic.py::test_2 PASSED                                             [100%]
Use of heavy context: I'm heavy
Slow context released


============================== 2 passed in 0.01s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! 
I actually thought about setting the scope but assumed it would precompute and store all instances beforehand (I tried scope="class" and the order of tests made me think so).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps run the tests one after another without initializing the object again, e.g.:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("params", LIST_OF_RANDOMIZED_PARAMS)
def test_one(params):
    state = very_slow_initialization(params)
    assert state.fast_test()
    assert state.another_fast_test()
```

or using separate functions for organization:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("params", LIST_OF_RANDOMIZED_PARAMS)
def test_main(params):
    state = very_slow_initialization(params)

    step_one(state)
    step_two(state)

def step_one(state):
    assert state.fast_test()

def step_two(state):
    assert state.another_fast_test()
```

Although it's a test script, you can still use functions to organize your code. In the version with separate functions you may even declare a fixture, in case the state may be needed in other tests, too:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=LIST_OF_RANDOMIZED_PARAMS)
def state(request):
    return very_slow_initialization(request.param)

def test_main(state):
    step_one(state)
    step_two(state)

def step_one(state):
    assert state.fast_test()

def step_two(state):
    assert state.another_fast_test()
```

I hope I didn't do a mistake here, but it should work like this.

Comment: You are right! This works however with some downsides (unless I am overlooking something):
If any test fails, then none of the following tests are done. Also, the whole test fails, so I get a less detailed overview.

Comment: @Smudoxo I see, that's a valid argument. But good that the other answer seemed to helped you :)